# SML counting within a pair of lists

Tags: sml

I am trying to write a function in SML that takes in a pair of lists. The first list in the pair is a list of integers and the second list is a list of booleans. Ex: (([3, 5, 9], [true, false, false])). I am having trouble with the proper syntax to return how many times 'true' is found in the second list.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to break this down.

1. Can you count the number of times a value is found in a list?
2. Can you pattern match out the second list in the tuple?

The first one can be accomplished by implementing a `count` function. A basic shell for that would look something like:

```
fun count (_, []) = ...
  | count (v, (x::xs)) = 
    if ... then ...
    else ...
```

For the second, well, you can see pattern-matching for binding names to the elements of a tuple in the above code.

Doing anything more would be doing your homework for you, and that would be a disservice.